# How to control Brush transaction effect in dc.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using dc.js to prototype a visual data analysis tool.
Concerning the brush feature of the library, how can I specify a behavior (**A** or **B**) to brush selection?

I had two different behaviors with similar code.

In **A**, selected bars are highlighted with 'teal' color, and non-selected get a gray color.

In **B**, selected bars are also highlighted with 'teal' color. However, this time it completely hides the non-selected bars.

Can someone tell me which function/feature should I be using/changing in order to define **A** or **B**?

**A**

```
     s.spendHistChart
       .width(350).height(200)
       .colors('teal')
       .centerBar(true)
       .dimension(cAmountDim)
       .group(spendHist)
       .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]))
       .elasticY(true)
```

**B**

```
         s.chart2
            .width(990).height(120)
            .colors('teal')
            .margins({top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 80})
            .dimension(s.moveMonths)
            .group(s.dateDimensionSpend)
            .centerBar(true)
            .gap(20)
            .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2013, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 11, 31)]))
            .elasticX(false)
            .round(d3.time.month.round)
            .alwaysUseRounding(true)
            .xUnits(d3.time.months);
```

For sure I am missing something. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is the intended behavior.

Crossfilter dimensions will only observe changes to other dimensions.

Filtering happens on the dimensions, but dc.js reads data from the groups.

Thus if a chart's group does not belong to its dimension, then the chart will observe its own filter, which is usually not the desired behavior.

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_group